# Problems loading the css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I load my page , I get an ERROR 403 message.

It seems that the browser cannot access the CSS file,

but in fact i don't have a CSS file.

My style is between the head tag:

GET https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/strong-lifts-5x5/stylesheet.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> New Responsive design web page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <meta name="viewport"    content= "width=device-width , initial-scale = 1.0">
    <style>
         body {
            background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/strong-lifts-5x5/light-grey+5x5.jpg);
            color:#000305;
            font-size:89.5%; /* Base font size is 14px*/
            font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
            line-height:1.5;
            text-align:left;
            width: 99%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
```

Comment: The link tag in your head is attempting to load a css file named `stylesheet.css`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" > this will load the stylesheet.css.

Comment: Yes  but if i delete it the page does't load and i get the message : 
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ea9jb1du/1/. No problem loading the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because this code:  `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />`
if you do not have a stylesheet.css relative to your index page then it will give you an error. Remove that and you will be fine.

Comment: when i remove it the page doesn't even load and i get this message instead:


This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>48652C2EC6A578E4</RequestId>
<HostId>
ppbIRii1/bMmf7hfL2V1XeJi0HqZr6N2NcXeWg2ZmQrhjBUTqwyptBH/EA/XMH+R
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Why is it xml file? Isn't it html? try moving the style part of the code up to under meta?

Comment: it doesn't work , i get the same error message if i delete <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

Comment: Try moving all the style code to stylesheet.css and actually have it. I'm not sure why you keep having the same error message (never had that before)

Answer (score 0):

When you get 403 error, it means you don have permission to access it. For some reason your request is forbidden. For example, I had this problem with login. When I wasn't login my css wouldn't load. But when I logged in it works. You should check your htaccess configuration or anything where you can edit permissions for your project.